# Is it possible to exceed Mongodb's document size limit by storing object Id in a single document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Suppose we have such a mongodb schema (I used the format from mongoose just for illustration purposes):

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    posts : [Schema.Types.ObjectId] // stores the _id field from post
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
    body : String
});
```

Since the maximum document size in mongodb is 16 MB, which is finite, wouldn't we run the risk of exceeding such a limit such the above schema (even if it is a every small risk ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: How would it **not** be possible to store too many entries in an array? I don't understand why you're asking this question?

Comment: Oh.. sry for the confusion.. My question is if it is possible to exceed mongodb's document size limit when posts : [Schema.Types.ObjectId] grows very large ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible for a very large number of posts.  The traditional way to overcome the limitation is to invert the schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },  // _id of the post's user
    body : String
});
```